# Binding to a CollectionViewSource Question

Tags: wpf, data-binding, collectionviewsource

My issue goes like that:

I have 2 ListBox:

one is bound to a collection called photos of type Photos and the other is bound to a CollectionViewSource which is bound to the same photos collection.

listBox1 -> photos (here the listBox1 is bound to the Default CollectionView of photos, of course and not directly to photos.)

ListBox2 -> cvs -> photos

both collection (the default one and my CVS) having a filter that reduce the items they show from 8 items to 5 items.

now i have 2 labels. one is bound to the Count property of the photos object and the other one is bound to the Count property where the source is the cvs (my CollectionViewSource) object.

the first label show the number 8 and as i see it, it is because the Count of photos stays 8 even though i am filterring it's default CollectionViewSource.

the second label shows the number 5.

what i learnt about binding to a cvs is that WPF unwrapps the source object from the cvs and the Path=Count is relevant to the underlying object which is photos and the number here should be 8 also.

does someone can explain me where i am worng?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding will not bind to the source collection but the view. The collection view also has a [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.count.aspx) property which returns the number of items in the (filtered) view rather than in the original collection.

*(You can use the debugger to see that the [`View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.view.aspx) property of the [`CollectionViewSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) normally will be an object which is an instance of [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) or one of its subclasses. The binding will implicitly bind to `View.Count`)*

To bind to the original count use the path `SourceCollection.Count`.

Comment: 1) we are talking about CollectionViewSource object and not him nor CollectionViewSource.View does have a Count Propery

2) When you want to bind to a property of the Wrapper object (the CollectionViewSource object in this case) you set the BindsDirectlyToSource in the binding objet to true. this means that we do not want to unwrap our source object from the CVS object and we want to bind to a property on the CVS object

3) I read it in my book WPF Unleashed by Nathan Adam.

Comment: Well, the thing is that the default interface for collection views (`ICollectionView`) does not have any count property but for most source collections you end up with an implementation that does. So this count that is displayed is indeed from the property i linked to in my answer as the binding implicitly binds to `View.Count` which normally just exists. Even if you bind to an `IEnumerable` the binding system will create an `IList` around it so probably even then there will be a count in the view.

Comment: That there will be a count property can also be deduced from the fact that 1. You do not create the view yourself 2. There is only one class in the framework which implements `ICollectionView` and that is `CollectionView`, which has said property.

Comment: ok, but if my BindsDirectlyToSource set to false the Count property i am binding to should be the count of the underliyng source object which is photos and not the CollectionViewSource itself... (this is exactly what BindsDirectlyToSource is for)

Comment: BindsDirectlyToSource will not bind to the source collection but to the CollectionViewSource, as this is the case the raw path `Count` will no longer bind at all since the CollectionViewSource has no such property. You should use the path `Source.Count` in that case.

Comment: H.B. i feel you don't point directly to my question..
in my case BindDirectlyToSource set to false so the Path=Count is referenced to the photos object which its count is 8 (you can see it in the other label that binds to photos.Count and you can see it through debugging. so why both labels that actually bind to the same property shows different values..?

Comment: You just do not seem to understand what i am saying, i answered that long ago: They do not bind to the same property, it implicitly binds to the `View.Count` which is **not the same** as the source's count since it takes the filter into account. You can either use `BindsDirectlyToSource` and `Source.Count` or you take the default behavior and get the collection from the View by setting the path to `SourceCollection.Count`.

Comment: If `BindsDirectlyToSource` is off it binds to the view, not the source collection.